How can I improve exception handling in the check_domain method of the MVT tool?
I’m working with the MVT (Mobile Verification Toolkit) tool and noticed that the check_domain method uses a broad except Exception block. This approach can lead to false positives when checking for domain indicators. Specifically, if URL parsing fails, the method falls back to a substring match on the URL without specific error handling, which can obscure the actual issues occurring during URL processing.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
try:
    # URL parsing logic
    ...
except Exception:
    # If URL parsing failed, we just try to do a simple substring match.
    for idx, ioc in domain_matcher.iter(url):
        if ioc["value"].lower() in url:
            self.log.warning(
                "Maybe found a known suspicious domain %s "
                'matching indicator "%s" from "%s"',
                url,
                ioc["value"],
                ioc["name"],
            )
            return ioc

    # If nothing matched, we can quit here.
    return None

I attempted to implement more specific exception handling by catching specific exceptions related to URL parsing (e.g., ValueError, URLError). I also considered logging the exception details for better debugging insights. However, I’m unsure how to effectively integrate this without cluttering the code or losing the current functionality.
I expected that by handling specific exceptions, I could better understand the nature of any failures during URL parsing and avoid falling back to substring matching when inappropriate. I want to ensure that the method provides more accurate results and clearer logs.
I believe that handling specific exceptions could provide better insights into errors and help avoid unintended matches.
What are some best practices for improving exception handling in this method?
